# Losing BluetoothGatt objetct of BLE connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I'm developing an APP that connect to a BLEDevice. This connection is managed by a Sticky Service that have a instance of a singleton that keep all the parameters of the BLE connection (BluetoothDevice,BluetoothGatt,BluetoothGattCallBack).

The behaviour of the APP is resumed in the next lines:

1. When i open the APP, i click on button that scan, bond and connect to
   the desire BLE Device.
2. Once it is connected, appear a Test button that allow me to test if
   the connection have been stablished correctly by reading a Gatt
   Characteristic of the BLE Device.
3. If i kill the app, the service still running due to be Sticky. The
   point is to not lose the conection with the BLE Device
4. Then, if i open the app again and i press the test button, it should
   work.

The problem comes in the point 4. When i click on the test button after close the app one time, i get the next error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)'
>   on a null object reference

According to my understanding, the problem is that the BluetoothGatt object is lost.

How should i proceed to not lose the BLE connection?

Comment: There is a similar project here https://github.com/milindafferent/sensor-Tag , perhaps this may help you.

Comment: it seems you set gatt variable to null or you get differenct instance of service/manager